# Duplicate Expandable Image Grid Loses Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an expandable image grid that I want to use multiple times on a single page. But If I want to use the expandable image grid more than once on that page the duplicate seems to lose its function, it no longer expands.

Example:

- Image Grid on top of page
- Div in middle
- Image Grid at bottom

The bottom grid loses its function, why is this? Heres a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yw1hgd8/4/) of my progress, I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
/*
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7243260-2']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
*/
```

CSS

```
/* default.css */
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

html { height: 100%; }

*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.container2 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.container > header {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 30px 50px 30px;
}

.container > header {
    padding: 60px 30px 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > header h1 {
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 38px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333;
}

.container > header h1 span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.main > p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 20px;
}

/* Header Style */
.codrops-top {
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.codrops-top a {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    color: #000;
}

.codrops-top span.right {
    float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}


/* Component.css */

.og-grid {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.og-grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 250px;
}

.og-grid li > a,
.og-grid li > a img {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.og-grid li.og-expanded > a::after {
    top: auto;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -15px;
}

.og-expander {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.og-expander-inner {
    padding: 50px 30px;
    height: 100%;
}

.og-close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.og-close::before,
.og-close::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #888;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.og-close::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.og-close:hover::before,
.og-close:hover::after {
    background: #333;
}

.og-fullimg,
.og-details {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.og-details {
    padding: 0 40px 0 20px;
}

.og-fullimg {
    text-align: center;
}

.og-fullimg img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.og-details h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 52px;
    padding: 40px 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.og-details p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #999;
}

.og-details a {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    outline: none;
}

.og-details a::before {
    content: '\2192';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.og-details a:hover {
    border-color: #999;
    color: #999;
}

.og-loading {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@-moz-keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {

    .og-expander h3 { font-size: 32px; }
    .og-expander p { font-size: 13px; }
    .og-expander a { font-size: 12px; }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    .og-fullimg { display: none; }
    .og-details { float: none; width: 100%; }

}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="container"> 
            <!--/ Codrops top bar -->
            <header class="clearfix">
                <h1>Thumbnail Grid <span>with Expanding Preview</span></h1> 
            </header>
            <div class="main">
                <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="img03"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-title="Sea lettuce" data-description="Bell pepper eggplant water spinach bell pepper radicchio kale artichoke earthnut pea beet greens carrot celtuce peanut radish mustard jícama tomato bamboo shoot quandong.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="img04"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p>Filler text by <a href="http://veggieipsum.com/">Veggie Ipsum</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!--/ Duplicate -->

    <div class="container"> 

            <header class="clearfix">
                <h1>Duplicate<span>Not expanding</span></h1>    
            </header>
            <div class="main">
                <ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/3.jpg" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="img03"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/4.jpg" data-title="Sea lettuce" data-description="Bell pepper eggplant water spinach bell pepper radicchio kale artichoke earthnut pea beet greens carrot celtuce peanut radish mustard jícama tomato bamboo shoot quandong.">
                            <img src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/images/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="img04"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p>Filler text by <a href="http://veggieipsum.com/">Veggie Ipsum</a></p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/js/grid.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                Grid.init();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="//tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/demoad.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open developer tools (F12 in Chrome) you can see what your problem is in the console when you click on the images that aren't working:

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure resource ''. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

The difference in in the href atrributes of your links, in the first component you use HTTPS and in the ones that aren't working you're just using HTTP.

---

**UPDATE:**

Looking again, I saw the main problem of the code wasn't the mixed content as i stated before. Diving in the plugin code i noticed that it isn't prepared to work with more than one component at the same page because it explicitly asks for the element with id `#og-grid` with a jQuery selector `var $grid = $( '#og-grid' )`.

The code hasn't been updated for four years now as you can see here: 
https://github.com/codrops/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview

So, if you really want to use it you'll need to adapt it to your needs. I gave it a try and got your code working with it:

https://jsfiddle.net/0yw1hgd8/5/

I've made several changes:

1. Changed the id of the duplicate `ul` from `og-grid` to `og-grid2`
2. Created a new version of the `Grid` object used in the plugin (Look at the `Grid2` definition in the fiddle)
3. Changed the context from `this` to `$grid` where `$.data()` function were used so it wouldn't interfere with the other (only in the new definition).
4. And finally, called the new object init function `Grid2.init();`

Comment: AarónBC, Thank you for helping. For someone new like me, how do I make the second component use HTTPS? Is it difficult?

Comment: Hi, I gave it a second look at your problem and code. please see the asnwer's update

Comment: AarónBC, WOW.. you know your stuff! Thank you for taking the time to make this work, I really appreciate it! Now say if I wanted to add a 3rd or 4th duplicate do I recreate steps 1,2 & 4 listed on your answer? I've tried in this Jsfiddle but Im not doing something right.. https://jsfiddle.net/Dunne08/0yw1hgd8/6/

Comment: Well, doing all the steps should do the job, but that wouldn't be optimal because we'd copy the `Grid` function over and over just to change one ID. So, if you want to have more than two we better start thinking about parameterizing the Grid function so that instead of having an ID hardcoded, we can pass a variable with the ID of the element we want to use. Please look at this new version of the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0yw1hgd8/7/

Comment: A very late reply but thank you for your help and taking the time to solve this. This is exactly what I needed thanks a lot!